# Calling toString from the main class trough polymorphism

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

I have an algorithm with a generic class called `Employee` and some specific classes that are inheriting from `Employee` as below:

```
abstract class Employee {
    private String name;
    private String document;

    public String toString(){
         return "\nName and Document";
    }
}

class Driver extends Employee {
    private String licencePlate;

    public String toString(){
        return "Plate: XXXXX";
    }
}

class TelOperator extends Employee {
    private String phone;

    public String toString(){
        return "Phone: XXX - XXXXXX";
    } 
}

class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        TelOperator telOp = new TelOperator();
        System.out.println(telOp);

        Driver driver = new Driver();
        System.out.println(driver);

    }
}
```

I'm looking for some way to avoid calling each object separately and to execute the `toString` method from the main class with the `toString` from the especific classes that inherit from it.
My output would be something like this:

//Driver

1. Name and Document
2. Plate: XXXXX

   ---

//Phone attendant

3. Name and Document
4. Phone: XXX - XXXXX

You can check the source code [here](https://ideone.com/h6TcHE).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add call to `super.toString()` in your child classes' `toString()` methods:-

```
public String toString() {
    return super.toString() + "\nPhone: XXX - XXXXXX";
}
```

Comment: Thats was really helpfull, and solved half of my problems. Is there any way that I can print all `toString` methods with the use of a foreach?

Comment: you can do it like this `Stream.of(new TelOperator(), new Driver()).forEach(emp -> System.out.println(emp.toString()));`

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create an object of the subclass and call their toString within the main's toString, if you want both printed out at once.  Hope I'm understanding your question correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Factory class for the employee and the factory makes the decision which subclass should be returned to the calling program. It then creates an instance of that subclass and then returns it to the calling program.

Hope I understood your question correctly.